# How to reduce compile time for a single compile-unit of header-only template-only code instead of refactoring/decomposing it?

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

I have a single compile unit of header-only template-only code.

I have seen several threads on compile time reduction for projects, make files, and decomposable compile units.
I acknowledge these approaches, but I want to consider code decomposition as last resort.

At the moment, I would like to understand why the compiler takes ages to compile a single given compile-unit, instead directly trying to refactor/decompose the unit.

## My Scenario:

I have the following files, that serve the purpose of automatic differentiation, however not for procedural but OO code.

```cpp
// number.hpp ----------------
template<typename App>
struct Generator{ /*...attributes and member-functions...*/ };

struct Number{ /*...attributes and member-functions...*/ };

Number operator+(Number x, Number y){ /*...implementation...*/ }
/*...further operators...*/

// base.hpp ----------------
template<typename Tfloat>
struct Base{ /*...*/ };

// ... functions and operators for Base

//total of ~5000 lines of code until this point (POSITION 1)

#ifdef __Generator__
#include"number"
template<>
struct Base<Number>; // .. with definitions of attributes and member-functions
#endif

// generator.cpp ----------------
#define __Generator__
#include"number.hpp"
#include"base.hpp"
int main(){
  Generator<Base<Number>> G;
  Base<Number> X;
  G.generate(X,"derived.hpp");
  return 0;
}

// derived.hpp ----------------
#include"base.hpp"
template<typename Tfloat, size_t n>
struct Derived: Base<Tfloat>{/*... ~30000 lines of code...*/};

// driver.cpp ----------------
#include"derived.hpp"
int main(){
  Derived<double,32> Y; // or <float,64>, or <half,64>, etc...
  Y.eval();
  return 0;
}
```

## How the code is used/ compiled

I use GCC 12.2 in Mingw64 on Windows 10 on a 32 core machine.

The `` generator`.cpp `` is quickly compiled and executed (performance of this executable is unimportant), creating the file `derived.hpp` uniquely for each provided `base.hpp`.

Next, the `driver.cpp` must be compiled (performance of this executable is very important).
This latter compilation is the thing that takes ages. I cannot understand why.

It seems to me that the compiler is aware that only one object of each template class must be created in each compilation.

I understand that at POSITION 1 it would be attractive to outsource parts into external cpp files, but this would require a lot of work.

## Question

Are there any causes from the presented code structure that give clear indication as to why it takes so long to compile?;
and if so, then how can these be removed in order to reduce compilation time?

Comment: So the problem is in the code you don't show? Hm. We have seen cases where machine generated initialization of HUGE arrays takes a very long time. Compilers are generally optimized for the type of code people write, not codes machines write.

Comment: "~30000 lines of code" looks like a pretty good indication to me. If these lines are full of template code...

Comment: The reason "why the compiler takes ages to compile" is always the same: C++ is just too complicated. It's a lot of work to instantiate all templates; figure out ***which*** templates need to be instantiated, etc...